# Offline js not detecting down internet

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I am using offline js for internet detecting up and down. 
My code is below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        Offline.options = {
            reconnect: {
                initialDelay: 10,
                delay: (5)
            }
        }
        Offline.on('up', internetUp);
        Offline.on('down', internetDown);

        function internetUp(event, data) {
            console.log("Internet is up.");
        }

        function internetDown(event, data) {
            console.log("Internet is down.");
        }
    });
```

I am facing the problem When internet is down there is no event fire and when internet is up both events are fired need help i am using offline-js 0.7.13 version.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if it works without a 3rd party module.

You can check the browser's `navigator.onLine` value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

In the above code, in your ready function you can attach an eventHandler to the window that detects online / offline events

```
window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events